# Select Image from Gallery and set it to DailogBox's Imageview in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, imageview

I have used dialog box in fragment and on FAB Click, when i choose image from gallery but that selected image cannot set it in to imageview.
my query is how to set selected image in dialog box?

how can i use `onActivityResult()` in my fragment?

Thanks in advance!!

here is my code..

```
     public class PizzasFragment extends Fragment {

  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pizza, container, false);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               final Dialog addDish = new Dialog(getActivity());
                addDish.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                addDish.setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
                imageDish = (ImageView) addDish.findViewById(R.id.IMGFood);

                imageDish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try {

                            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                            startActivityForResult(i, SELECT_PICTURE);


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                    "Select Image From Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                            // TODO: handle exception
                        }

                    }
                });

    return rootView;
}

 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (data != null) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            imageDish.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            imageDish.setEnabled(true);
            Log.d("picturepath",""+picturePath);
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Try Again!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: why you are not using the uri directly to setImage??

Comment: try this on onActivityResult: `imageDish.setImageBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(activity.getContentResolver(), data.getData()));`

Comment: @Fer how can i define activity in fragment.?

Comment: @VivekMishra i tried uri but not working....can u share example for this..?

Comment: @NikitaSukhadiya activity is `getActivity()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for onActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }
```

Comment: is your onActivityResult method getting called. Debug and check it